# Make a line graph without labels

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, graph, linegraph

I'm making a stock market game in which the application scrubs the internet for different stocks. I saw an idea for a stock game online, [I do not own this image]:

https://dribbble.com/shots/4161894-Invest-App-UI-Dark-Version

The image on the right has tiny line graphs to show the change in stock value based on previous values of that stock.

and I'm wondering if there is a way to simply make a line graph that applies the values to the previous stock amounts earlier in time using java. I do NOT want it to be a complete graph, with labels and X & Y markers, I just want the line itself to be present

I've tried using JavaFX line graphs, but it had a background and labels and other numbers that I didn't want for the aesthetic.

Comment: @too_broad_sayers If you'd know something about JavaFX then you would realize that this question is just the oposite of beeing too broad. Instead it touches a real API problem which is well worth discussing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the chart consists of many parts (f.i. axis, background grid, legend, graph). Your task is to configure the state of all such that only those you want are showing, in your case (more or less) only the graph.

Astonishingly, nearly everything is configurable to be either visible or not - except for the axis: these have to be manually removed from their parent.

A code snippet to undecorate a LineChart:

```
protected void undecorate(LineChart chart) {
    chart.setLegendVisible(false);
    chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
    chart.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
    chart.setHorizontalZeroLineVisible(false);
    chart.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
    chart.setVerticalZeroLineVisible(false);
    undecorateAxis(chart.getXAxis());
    undecorateAxis(chart.getYAxis());
}

protected void undecorateAxis(Axis axis) {
    // trying to hide: not working
    // xAxis.setVisible(false);
    // configure all ticks/label to not visible doesn't work
    // if (axis instanceof ValueAxis)
    //    ((ValueAxis<?>) axis).setMinorTickVisible(false);
    // axis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
    //axis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
    // remove from parent does work
    Pane parent = (Pane) axis.getParent();
    parent.getChildren().removeAll(axis);
}
```